# Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE in Rselenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I get this error when my google chrome update from 118 to 119. I have been changed the chromedriver also.

Error in checkError(res) :
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘RSelenium’ was built under R version 4.3.2
2: In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "119.0.6045.105", verbose = FALSE,  :
Could not determine server status.

This is my client_server connected code:

```
client_server <- rsDriver(
  browser = "chrome",
  chromever = "119.0.6045.105",
  verbose = FALSE,
  port = free_port(),
)
```

I expect it will be open chrome automatically and I can test there by Rselenium